# c# Windows Forms: Form Close Event Cancel Button

Tags: c#, windows, forms, events

I have a Form_Closing event that prompts the user if the file has been changed to save if changes have been made to the file (standard Yes/No/Cancel options). Cancel is where things don't work as they should.

If I select File -> New and there is an existing file with changes I get prompted as expected, bit when I select Cancel the new form is presented rather than staying on the current form and I end up with two forms open at once.

Here is MainForm (File New) code:

```
       if (editForm != null)
        {
            // Close existing Editor form
            editForm.Close();
            // Open new form
            editForm = new EditorForm(this);
            // Close Form Events
            editForm.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(EditorForm_Closing);
            editForm.Show();
            editForm.Focus();

      else
        {
            // Open new Editor 
            editForm = new EditorForm(this);
            // Close Form Events
            editForm.Closing += new CancelEventHandler(EditorForm_Closing);
            editForm.Show();
            editForm.Focus();
        }
```

Here is my EditForm_Closing:

```
  if (editForm != null)
        {
            if (editForm.diagramComponent.Model.Modified)
            {
                DialogResult res = MessageBox.Show(this, "The project has been modified. Save changes?", "Save changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
                if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    if (!editForm.HasFileName)
                    {
                        if (this.saveEditorDialog1.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                        {
                            this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(this.saveEditorDialog1.FileName);
                            editForm.FileName = this.saveEditorDialog1.FileName;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.ActiveDiagram.SaveSoap(editForm.FileName);
                    }

                }
                else if (res == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                }
            }
```

Not sure how to make the correlation between the Cancel close event and my File -> New. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT:** Added my EditForm_Closing Event.

Comment: can you show the code in the EditorForm_Closing as well?

Comment: also the code that handles showing the dialog?

Comment: see my answer below; it looks like the cancel is handled properly; the only thing i can think of is that somehow editForm is being set to null prior to the calls shown for your File->New code.  if nothing jumped out at me i would try setting a breakpoint at the top of the code you pasted in your File->New code to see what's going on.

Comment: removed my answer as it was apparently not relevant :).  so i can't recall for sure and don't have time to test, but maybe you have to call Close() on the window in the Form_Closing event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing your main form's code with the following:

```
if (editForm != null) {
    // try closing existing Editor form
    editForm.Close();
    if(!editForm.IsDisposed) // close was canceled.
        return;
}

// Open new form
editForm = new EditorForm(this);
// Close Form Events
editForm.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler('suitable method here');
editForm.Show();
editForm.Focus();
```

Comment: I cannot test whether it works, and if it does, make sure you disconnect the `FormClosingEventHandler` appropriately in the handler as well (if you're not canceling, that is, allowing the editor to close).

Answer (score 2):

Your Closing event handler should set the editForm property back to null.  So check it like this:

```
if (editForm != null) {
    editForm.Close();
    if (editForm != null) return;  // Close was cancelled
    // etc..
}
```

Or just use a private boolean member.

Comment: ahhh, i added return; to my DialogResult.Cancel and that seemed to work when i try to just close the form thank you! however, when i click file -> new it still opens a second window.

Comment: Are you setting the editForm field to null in the Closing event handler?  Important, you don't want to leak the instance.